# How to set a Default Value to KeyboardDatePicker

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I have a react hook form, and I want to set the default value of KeyboardDatePicker from the data that come of props. How can I do it?

```
        <KeyboardDatePicker
            name="startDate"
            format="dd/MM/yyyy"
            margin="normal"
            inputVariant="outlined"
            ref={register}                
            label={t('Data Início')}
            value={fromSelectedDate}
            onChange={handleDateChangeFrom}
            disablePast
            cancelLabel={t('cancel')}
            error={errors.startDate}
        />
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set the default date, whenever you declare your "fromSelectedDate" i.e. it should be something like this :

```
const [fromSelectedDate,setfromSelectedDate] = useState(new Date());
```

- It will set the default date as Today's date.